# How to make an image rendering from database as link

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
   <div style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:5px; padding:16px; margin-bottom:16px; height:250px;">
      <img src="'.$row['college_image'].'" alt="" class="img-responsive" >
      <p align="center"><strong><a href="#">'. $row['product_name'] .'</a></strong></p>
      <h4 style="text-align:center;" class="text-danger" >'.$row['search_link'].'</h4>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to make above img tag as clickable link
Thanks

Comment: And your Problem is?

Comment: here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/, it's basic html <a><img></a>

Comment: wrapping anchor tag around image tag isn't working

Comment: _"isn't working"_ means what exactly? Please show what you have tried. We cannot help without seeing that.

Comment: "_wrapping anchor tag around image tag isn't working_" You gave that `<a>` tag a `href` with an URL to point to?!

Comment: yes i did, but that url should also be rendered from db

Comment: How about you update your question with what you've already tried and isn't working? And please explain what "_isn't working_" means. Wrong URL? Link not showing up?

Comment: got it thanks..i was giving url but it was inside anchor tag in db

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
    <div style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:5px; padding:16px; margin-bottom:16px; height:250px;">
        <!--- MAGIC --->
        <a href="<YOUR_URL_FROM_DATABASE">
            <img src="'.$row['college_image'].'" alt="" class="img-responsive" >
        </a>
        <!--- /MAGIC --->
        <p align="center"><strong><a href="#">'. $row['product_name'] .'</a></strong></p>
        <h4 style="text-align:center;" class="text-danger" >'.$row['search_link'].'</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```